# Python tkinter removing nested functions

Tags: python, tkinter, nested-function

So I was developing a GUI with tkinter and I have realised that I have so many nested functions in my code that I think it is not a good practice. However, I think my code will not work without using them.

My code:

```
def convertFiles():
    files = []
    cname = my_lb.curselection()
    for i in cname:
        op = my_lb.get(i)
        files.append(op)
    if files == []:
        messagebox.showinfo('', 'Please choose a file')
    else:
        pass_files = []
        decrypted_data = []

        if messagebox.askquestion('Convert', 'Are you sure to convert your file(s)?'):
            kill_command = ["gpgconf", "--kill", "gpg-agent"]
            kill_out = subprocess.check_output(kill_command, universal_newlines=False)
            disable_button()

            for val in files:
                pass_files.append(f'{pwd}/.password-store/{val}')

            newWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
            newWindow.title("Passphrase for Asymmetric Decryption")
            newWindow.geometry("400x150")
            newWindow.resizable(False,False)
            
            tk.Label(newWindow,text ="Please put your passphrase for decryption.").place(x=0,y=0)

            passp_entry = tk.Entry(newWindow)
            passp_entry.place(x=0,y=30)

            def get_entry():
                passp = passp_entry.get()
                if passp:

                    for x in range(0, len(pass_files)):
                        command1 = ["gpg", "-d", "--quiet", "--yes", "--pinentry-mode=loopback", f"--passphrase={passp}", f'{pass_files[x]}.gpg']
                        out = subprocess.check_output(command1, universal_newlines=False)
                        decrypted_data.append(out)
                    print('Asymmetric decryption is complete.')
                    newWindow.destroy()
        
            add_button = tk.Button(newWindow, text='Enter', command=get_entry)
            add_button.place(x=0, y=60)
```

I really just want to know if `get_entry()` can be put outside and be called inside of the `convertFiles()` function. I think that might not be possible because `get_entry()` needs variables that is inside the `convertFiles()`. I will be happy to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to pass those required variables to the function via argumments.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can move `get_entry()` out of `convertFiles()`, but you need to pass those required variables to the function via arguments:

```py
def get_entry(win, passp, pass_files, decrypted_data):
    if passp:
        for file in pass_files:
            command1 = ["gpg", "-d", "--quiet", "--yes", "--pinentry-mode=loopback", f"--passphrase={passp}", f'{file}.gpg']
            out = subprocess.check_output(command1, universal_newlines=False)
            decrypted_data.append(out)
        print('Asymmetric decryption is complete.')
        win.destroy()


def convertFiles():
    files = []
    cname = my_lb.curselection()
    for i in cname:
        op = my_lb.get(i)
        files.append(op)
    if files == []:
        messagebox.showinfo('', 'Please choose a file')
    else:
        pass_files = []
        decrypted_data = []

        if messagebox.askquestion('Convert', 'Are you sure to convert your file(s)?') == "yes":
            kill_command = ["gpgconf", "--kill", "gpg-agent"]
            kill_out = subprocess.check_output(kill_command, universal_newlines=False)
            disable_button()

            for val in files:
                pass_files.append(f'{pwd}/.password-store/{val}')

            newWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
            newWindow.title("Passphrase for Asymmetric Decryption")
            newWindow.geometry("400x150")
            newWindow.resizable(False,False)

            tk.Label(newWindow,text ="Please put your passphrase for decryption.").place(x=0,y=0)

            passp_entry = tk.Entry(newWindow)
            passp_entry.place(x=0,y=30)

            add_button = tk.Button(newWindow, text='Enter',
                                   command=lambda: get_entry(newWindow, passp_entry.get(), pass_files, decrypted_data))
            add_button.place(x=0, y=60)
```